# Counting with restrictions in die throws

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, factorial

So I have this homework question.

A die is thrown 10 times, where the die has 6 faces labeled 1, 2, …, 6. Each outcome will be a sequence of 10 faces (i.e., 10 digits), where each face is one of the 6 values.

What is the number of possible outcomes where face 2 comes up exactly 3 times?

My first approach is to take the number of combinations of die that aren't 2 which would be $6^7$ and multiply it by the number of combinations of 10 die where 3 of them have 2 facing up: $3^{10}$. For a total combinations of $ 6^7 * 3^{10}$. Does this approach make sense or am I missing something?

Comment: You seem to have at least *some* knowledge of what is going on, but the numbers you are using are completely off.  Remember your multiplication principle.  $6^7$ sounds like you have seven steps, each with six options available.  $6^7$ is the number of ways to throw the dice seven times in sequence where twos as well as any other number are allowed.  $3^{10}$ is the number of ways to throw ten dice all showing 1,2, or 3.  Instead, break into the steps: 1) Pick which three spaces are used by twos.  2) From left-to-right for each non-two space, choose which non-two number is used there.

Comment: Remember that any such proposed formula should work in extreme cases.  How many ways are there for a die to be thrown ten times where every face comes up as a two?  Following the proposed formula in your post it would seem you think it would be $6^0\cdot 10^{10}$ instead of just $1$.

Comment: So my intuition is that the answer will be (Total possible combinations of having 3 2s within 10 choices) * (Total possible combinations of remaining dice).

Comment: Given that (Total possible combinations of having 3 2s within 10 choices) = $3^{10}$ and (total possible combinations of remaining dice) = $(10-3)^6$ I feel like that should make sense no? The formula would be: $ T = n^{10} * (10-n)^6. $ Where n is the number of dice that need to be a particular number which is 0<n<10. So the answer would be $3^{10} * 7^6 $. Does that work as an answer?

Comment: No, it does not.  Again, stop trying to find a general formula for now and use your multiplication principle.  I gave you a correct multiplication principle setup in my first comment.

Comment: So $5^7$ would be the number of ways to roll the remaining die and $10^3$ would be the number of ways to organize the 3 heads up 2s?

Comment: Wait no the number of ways to organize the 3 heads up 2s would be $(10!/(10-3)!)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A paraphrasing of the multiplication principle

> To count the number of outcomes of a scenario, if you can describe *every* outcome *uniquely* via a sequence of steps such that the number of options available for a step does not depend on the specific choices made at previous steps (*though the available options themselves may vary*), the total number of outcomes is the product of the number of options available at each step.

Here, we use multiplication principle to count.

*Step 1:* Pick which three out of the ten available positions are occupied by twos (*simultaneously*).

*Step 2a-2g:* From left to right, in the unoccupied spaces pick one of the five numbers to occupy that space.

---

For example, one such sequence of choices will result in the outcome $2~2~5~2~1~3~3~1~1~1$.  To do this, in step one I may pick to have the twos occupy the first second and fourth spaces:  $2~2~\underline{~}~2~\underline{~}~\underline{~}~\underline{~}~\underline{~}~\underline{~}~\underline{~}$

Then in step 2a: I pick the number $5$, leaving me with $2~2~5~2~\underline{~}~\underline{~}~\underline{~}~\underline{~}~\underline{~}~\underline{~}$

Then in step 2b: I pick the number $1$, leaving me with $2~2~5~2~1~\underline{~}~\underline{~}~\underline{~}~\underline{~}~\underline{~}$, and picking $3$ for 2c, $3$ for 2d, etc...

---

**Things to check:**

- Is in fact **every** sequence of ten dice rolls with *exactly* three $2$'s achievable via **at least one** sequence of choices using the above setup?
- Is in fact **every** sequence of ten dice rolls with *exactly* three $2$'s achievable via **at most one** sequence of choices using the above setup?
- Is the number of options available at each step independent of the specific choices made earlier?

---

Now, finally that we are hopefully on the same page, we can make it to the calculations.

How many ways can we complete step 1:?  In how many ways can we pick three of the ten available positions to be occupied by the twos?  We have **ten** available and we want to **choose** the **three** positions.

> This can be done in $10$ choose $3$, i.e. $\binom{10}{3}=\frac{10!}{3!7!}$ ways.  Not $10^3$ and not $\frac{10!}{7!}$.  Remember that we are choosing them simultaneously, so we use the binomial coefficient.  If we were to have broken this down as "pick the location of the first two" followed by "pick the location of the second two" etc... we would have overcounted because had we picked the locations in a different order it would have resulted in the same final sequence despite having used different choices at the steps to get there.

How many ways can you complete step 2a?  How many ways can you pick a number from $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ that isn't a $2$?  I.e. How many ways can you pick a number from $\{1,3,4,5,6\}$?

> $5$ ways.

And then 2b? 2c?... 2g?  Taking all of these together as one step, how many ways then can you complete step $2$?  I.e. How many ways can you fill the unoccupied spaces from left to right with a non-two number?

> $\underbrace{5\cdot 5\cdots 5}_{7~\text{times}} = 5^7$ ways

So, our final total number of outcomes?

> $\binom{10}{3}5^7$

A general formula for exactly $k$ twos rolled in $n$ rolls with an $s$-sided die (*where $2$ is one of the available sides and all sides different*)?

> $\binom{n}{k}(s-1)^{n-k}$

Comment: Thank you so much. Seeing it written out helps a lot.